# Script for selecting and renaming a directory for multiple xampp concept

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, lamp, xampp

I have installed xampp 5.6 and xampp 7.0 on my ubuntu system. I have named each of the installation folders as lampp5.6 and lampp7.0, so that whenever switching happens i need to rename the desired directory to lampp. I need a script which asks the user to select a version and renames the selected version directory to lampp and start the xampp server.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before but with different version than yours.. Assume I have PHP 5.2 in `/opt/lampp5.2` and PHP 5.6 in `/opt/lampp`

In `/opt` I make two very simple files, `start_lampp5.2.sh` and `start_lampp5.6.sh`:

1. ./start_lampp5.2.sh

   ```
     #!/usr/bin/env sh

     if [ -d "lampp5.2" ]; then
       mv "lampp" "lampp5.6"
       mv "lampp5.2" "lampp"
     fi

     python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
   ```
2. ./start_lampp5.6.sh

   ```
     #!/usr/bin/env sh

     if [ -d "lampp5.6" ]; then
       mv "lampp" "lampp5.2"
       mv "lampp5.6" "lampp"
     fi

     python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
   ```

I am not shell expert so it's just works for me. Maybe you can modify it for your versions

**Update:** I am now a shell expert. And I have created my own XAMPP-like (with support PHP5 and 7) here https://github.com/gnulinuxid/alphp

Answer (score 0):

## Use this script to start and stop two different lampp in Linux

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/lampp
#
#touch /var/lock/lampp
DIR7="/opt/lampp7"
DIR5="/opt/lampp5"
# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start5)
   if [ ! -d $DIR5 ]; then
           /etc/init.d/lampp stop
   echo "Starting lampp 5"
           /opt/lampp/lampp start
    else
            /opt/lampp/lampp stop
    `which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp7
    `which mv` /opt/lampp5 /opt/lampp
            /opt/lampp/lampp start
    fi
    ;;
  start7)
   if [ ! -d $DIR7 ]; then
           /opt/lampp/lampp stop
   echo "Starting lampp 7"
           /opt/lampp/lampp start
    else
            /opt/lampp/lampp stop
    `which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp5
    `which mv` /opt/lampp7 /opt/lampp
        /opt/lampp/lampp start
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping lampp"
    /opt/lampp/lampp stop
    ;;
  status)
    /opt/lampp/lampp status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lampp {start5|start7|status|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

### When using more than 2 lampp use the below script

#### Example: If you are using PHP5.5 PHP5.6 and PHP7.1

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/lampp
#
# Some things that run always
#touch /var/lock/lampp
DIR71="/opt/lampp71"
DIR55="/opt/lampp55"
DIR56="/opt/lampp56"
# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
#Lampp 71 section
  start71)
        if [ ! -d $DIR71 ]; then
echo "Already Running PHP Version 7.1"
echo "Please check status:- /opt/lampp/lampp status"
        elif [ -d "$DIR56" ]; then
echo "we consider php 5.5 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp55
`which mv` /opt/lampp71 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
        elif [ -d "$DIR55" ]; then
echo "we consider php 5.6 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp56
`which mv` /opt/lampp71 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
fi
  ;;
#Lampp 56 section
  start56)
        if [ ! -d $DIR56 ]; then
echo "Already Running PHP Version 5.6"
echo "Please check status:- /opt/lampp/lampp status"
        elif [ -d "$DIR71" ]; then
echo "we consider php 5.5 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp55
`which mv` /opt/lampp56 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
        elif [ -d "$DIR55" ]; then
echo "we consider php 7.1 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp71
`which mv` /opt/lampp56 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
fi
   ;;
#Lampp PHP5 section
  start55)
        if [ ! -d $DIR55 ]; then
echo "Already Running PHP 5.5"
echo "Please check status:- /opt/lampp/lampp status"
        elif [ -d "$DIR56" ]; then
echo "we consider php 7.1 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp71
`which mv` /opt/lampp55 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
        elif [ -d "$DIR71" ]; then
echo "we consider php 5.6 is running"
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
`which mv` /opt/lampp /opt/lampp56
`which mv` /opt/lampp55 /opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/lampp start
fi
   ;;
#Other Valid input
  stop)
    echo "Stopping lampp"
    /opt/lampp/lampp stop
    ;;
  status)
    /opt/lampp/lampp status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lampp {start55|start71|start56|status|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Good, maybe you could add some words on how to use it, to improve your answer.  Adding some info on the rationale behind your script may also be useful.